# Fetching the value of particular user returning 'none'

Tags: python, postgresql, pgadmin

- I am working with postgres database. I am trying to fetch the value of the `designation`column but is it returning `none`.
- Email id and password is being entered by the user and then the particular column of particular user is being searched which will return the value of the 'designation' column.
- `application.py`

```
            email_entered = request.form['email']
            password_entered = request.form['password']
            # check the role of the user
            sql_role_query = """SELECT users.designation FROM users WHERE users.email = %s"""
            role = cursor.execute(sql_role_query, record_to_search)
            print("Executed role query")
            print(role)
            if(role == 'Admin'):
                return redirect(url_for('listuser'))
            else:
                return redirect(url_for('createuser'))
            connection.commit()
```

- When doing `print(role)` it is returning `none`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must fetch results after calling `execute`.

Try to do next:

```
cursor.execute(sql_role_query, record_to_search)
role = cursor.fetchone()
```